# new to python, totally confused why this script wont work?

Tags: python

im super new to python, and tried to modify a script i found, but it wont work no matter what i do. im trying to get it to allow me to say one thing if 1 is entered and say something else if 2 is entered... please help :( here is the code

```
    #Computer attempts to guess a number you choose between 1 and 100 in 10 tries
answer = 'yes'
print ("Please, think of a number between 1 and 200. I am about to try to guess it in 20 tries.")
while answer == "yes":
    NumOfTry = 20
    NumToGuess = 50
    LimitLow = 1
    LimitHigh = 200
    while NumOfTry != 0:
        try:
            print ("I try: ",NumToGuess)
            print ("Please type: 1 for my try is too high")
            print ("             2 for my try is too low")
            print ("             3 I guessed your number")
            HumanAnswer  = int (input("So did I guess right?"))
            if 1 < HumanAnswer > 3:
                print ("Please enter a valid answer. 1, 2 and 3 are the valid choice")
                NumOfTry = NumOfTry + 1
            if HumanAnswer == 1:
                LimitHigh = NumToGuess
                print ("Hmm, so your number is between ",LimitLow, "and ", LimitHigh)
                NumOfTry = NumOfTry - 1
                print (NumOfTry, "attempts left")
                NumToGuess = int (((LimitHigh - LimitLow)/2) + LimitLow)
                if NumToGuess <= LimitLow:
                    NumToGuess = NumToGuess + 1
                if LimitHigh - LimitLow == 2:
                    NumToGuess = LimitLow + 1
            elif HumanAnswer == 2:
                LimitLow = NumToGuess
                print ("Hmm, so your number is between ",LimitLow, "and ", LimitHigh)
                NumOfTry = NumOfTry - 1
                print (NumOfTry, "attempts left")
                NumToGuess = int (((LimitHigh - LimitLow)/2) + LimitLow)
                if NumToGuess <= LimitLow:
                    NumToGuess = NumToGuess + 1
                if LimitHigh - LimitLow == 2:
                    NumToGuess = LimitLow + 1
            elif HumanAnswer == 3:
                print ("Woo hoo! I won")
                NumOfTry = 0
                answer = input ('Do you want to play again? (yes=1/no=2)')
                if 'yes':
                print ("ok")
                if 'no':
                print ("thanks for playing")
```

Comment: What does "wont work" mean? You've explained what you're trying to do; what does this do differently? If you get an exception, copy and paste the traceback into the question. If you get incorrect answers, tell us what they are and why that's incorrect. More generally, see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for what information (including, but not limited to, code) should go into a good question.

Comment: First, you have everything in a `try:` block with nothing to catch whatever exceptions might happen, so you're basically telling Python "run all this code, but don't tell me when an error happens". Remove that `try:`, then fix all the errors it finds first.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Actually, a `try` with no `except` isn't saying "don't tell me when an error happens", it's saying "just raise a `SyntaxError` immediately"… (But you're right that removing that line is the first step, of course.)

Comment: Anyway, there are a lot of problems with this code you found, even besides the formatting that you broke. For example, `1 < HumanAnswer > 3` is not a useful comparison to do. I'd suggest not starting with bad code before you've learned enough to debug other people's problems; find something different to play with.

Comment: This code is just full of a million problems. Looking at it for a just a moment shows a bunch of errors.

Comment: Unlike most programming languages, `1 < HumanAnswer > 3` is in fact legal Python. Of course, it is always False, so not very useful. You probably mean `1 <= HumanAnswer <= 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this fixes it: when you used the try: keyword, you did not follow up with an except:, and other than that, I tested it and works fine.

```
answer = 'yes'
print ("Please, think of a number between 1 and 200. I am about to try to guess it in 20 tries.")
while answer == "yes":
    NumOfTry = 20
    NumToGuess = 50
    LimitLow = 1
    LimitHigh = 200
    while NumOfTry != 0:
        try:
            print ("I try: ",NumToGuess)
            print ("Please type: 1 for my try is too high")
            print ("             2 for my try is too low")
            print ("             3 I guessed your number")
            HumanAnswer  = int (input("So did I guess right?"))
            if 1 < HumanAnswer > 3:
                print ("Please enter a valid answer. 1, 2 and 3 are the valid choice")
                NumOfTry = NumOfTry + 1
            if HumanAnswer == 1:
                LimitHigh = NumToGuess
                print ("Hmm, so your number is between ",LimitLow, "and ", LimitHigh)
                NumOfTry = NumOfTry - 1
                print (NumOfTry, "attempts left")
                NumToGuess = int (((LimitHigh - LimitLow)/2) + LimitLow)
                if NumToGuess <= LimitLow:
                    NumToGuess = NumToGuess + 1
                if LimitHigh - LimitLow == 2:
                    NumToGuess = LimitLow + 1
            elif HumanAnswer == 2:
                LimitLow = NumToGuess
                print ("Hmm, so your number is between ",LimitLow, "and ", LimitHigh)
                NumOfTry = NumOfTry - 1
                print (NumOfTry, "attempts left")
                NumToGuess = int (((LimitHigh - LimitLow)/2) + LimitLow)
                if NumToGuess <= LimitLow:
                    NumToGuess = NumToGuess + 1
                if LimitHigh - LimitLow == 2:
                    NumToGuess = LimitLow + 1
            elif HumanAnswer == 3:
                print ("Woo hoo! I won")
                NumOfTry = 0
                answer = input ('Do you want to play again? (yes=1/no=2)')
                if 'yes':
                    print ("ok")
                if 'no':
                    print ("thanks for playing")
        except:
            print("Out of tries!")
```

Comment: There are still a TON of errors in this. The code basically needs to just be rewritten.

Comment: I realize that, I just fixed it so that it ran in shell. I disapprove of the various blemishes, but I'm not going to fix all that.

Comment: omg thank you!!! today was my first day coding so all the feedback about all the errors and python talk were a little off putting and super confusing but this is perfect! finally it doesnt immediately crash on startup!

Comment: I'd suggest working on your organization and try to follow some general practices when coding, like skipping lines between chunks of code, to make it more readable.

Comment: Also, take time to read documentation on the basic functions before you try to use them, like with the try: statement.

Answer (score 0):

Fix last if block

EDIT:

```
if answer == 'yes':
    print ("ok")
if answer ==  'no':
    print ("thanks for playing")
```

You should have an `except` block, but in this case you don't need `try` either

Comment: im still confused, how do i fix it?

Comment: How is this an answer? That most likely is not the problem, because indentation gets messed up when being put into SO. What about using `try` but not `except`?

Comment: That's true, I didn't read it entirely. There are more mistakes

Comment: even with that fix it still wont run... this is so agravating